# How to make a prompt in C

Tags: c, linux, debian, cs50

New programmer here, I have a few lines of code that I've finally managed to get to function but I'm running into a bit of a design issue. The code itself, at least to me, function as intended but I don't know how to get my terminal to display "Insert number here". This is how to code currently looks.

```
#include "cs50.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

int n;
do
{
n = GetInt();
printf("Your number is!"/n);
}
while (n<1)
{
return n;
}
}
```

I'm looking for a way to get the same outcome as n = get_int ("Insert number:  "); but that method brings up errors such as:

```
prompt.c:10:7: warning: implicit declaration of function 'get_int' is
      invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
{ n = get_int("Insert number here %i\n", n);
```

or if I'm using n = GetInt("Insert number:   "); I get this error message.

```
prompt.c:10:14: error: too many arguments to function call, expected 0,
      have 2
{ n = GetInt("Insert number here %i\n", n);
      ~~~~~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/cs50.h:87:1: note: 'GetInt' declared here
int GetInt(void);
^
1 error generated.
```

Is there a way to get this to function so my terminal can prompt me with "Insert number here:  ". Thank you and cheers!

Comment: I'm afraid that you'll have to add `cs50.h` to be able to get meaningful responses. As it stands this question does not qualify for minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/, see also http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/stringstream/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print "Insert Number here:", you may use the prinf function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int testInteger;
    printf("Insert Number here: ");
    scanf("%d", &testInteger);  
    printf("Your Number is %d",testInteger);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This actually fixed everything, wow, thank you so much. Never knew there was a scanf function out there, learned something new today! Thanks mate.

Comment: Have a nice day. After you've learnt C, please consider learning C++